# How to draw four boundary rounded corner in canvas for qr code scanner Journeyapp Zxing?

Tags: canvas, zxing

How to draw four boundary rounded corner in canvas for journeyapps zxing qr code scanner Java code? Here is the code that I used. Just a rectangle with no rounding. How to create a rounded rectangle with custom radius.

Please see imag

[image: 1]

This is my java code, but the corners are square instead of round.

```
// Length rate of line and frame
private float mLineRate = 0.1f;

// Line depth
private float mLineDepth =
        TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

// Line color
private int mLineColor = Color.rgb(244, 165, 37);

    @Override
    public void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
        refreshSizes();
        if (framingRect == null || previewSize == null) {
            return;
        }

        final Rect frame = framingRect;
        final Size previewSize = this.previewSize;

        final int width = getWidth();
        final int height = getHeight();

// [Custom start] Draw 4 corner lines
    paint.setColor(mLineColor);
    canvas.drawRect(frame.left, frame.top,frame.left + frame.width() * mLineRate,frame.top + mLineDepth, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(frame.left, frame.top, frame.left + mLineDepth, frame.top + frame.height() * mLineRate, paint);

    canvas.drawRect(frame.right - frame.width() * mLineRate, frame.top, frame.right, frame.top + mLineDepth, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(frame.right - mLineDepth, frame.top, frame.right, frame.top + frame.height() * mLineRate, paint);

    canvas.drawRect(frame.left,frame.bottom - mLineDepth,frame.left + frame.width() * mLineRate, frame.bottom, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(frame.left, frame.bottom - frame.height() * mLineRate, frame.left + mLineDepth, frame.bottom, paint);

    canvas.drawRect(frame.right - frame.width() * mLineRate, frame.bottom - mLineDepth, frame.right, frame.bottom, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(frame.right - mLineDepth, frame.bottom - frame.height() * mLineRate, frame.right, frame.bottom, paint);
    // [Custom end]
```

Please help me.

Comment: I can only do in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Skip this and use lottiefiles on viewfinder. This is very hatic.

Comment: Please try and answer the question itself rather than suggesting a completely different technology. Thanks!

Comment: Sure you can make custom view like above and put that into top of zxing scanner. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> You can make rounded transparent custom view (DecoratedBarcodeView) which will act as round viewfinder and behind you can put above green rounder coner.

```
  class RoundedCornerCanvasView : View {
        private var mPaint: Paint? = null
        private var mCornerRadius = 0f
    
        constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
            init()
        }
    
        constructor(context: Context?, @Nullable attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
            init()
        }
    
        private fun init() {
            mPaint = Paint()
            mPaint!!.color = Color.BLACK
            mPaint!!.alpha = 20
            mPaint!!.isAntiAlias = true
            mCornerRadius = 30f // Customize the corner radius here
        }
    
        override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas)
    
            val width = canvas.width
            val height = canvas.height
            // Draw the rounded corner overlay
            val path = Path()
            path.addRoundRect(RectF(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat()), mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW)
            canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE)
            canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#50000000")) // Customize the overlay color here
        }
    }
```